# LoggerFactory.create() vs LoggerFactory.getLogger() - Java

Tags: java, logging, loggerfactory

I cam across the following Logger definition in my Java code and noticed that the following LoggerFactory uses the .create() method. I tried to locate good documentation to explain the difference between `LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass())` and `LoggerFactory.create(getClass())` but seem to have difficulties figuring out what exactly they do differently.

The package supporting the imports is called: `javautils-lib-3.0.jar`.

```
import utils.log.ILogger;
import utils.log.Log;
import utils.log.LogLevel;
import utils.log.Logger;
import utils.log.LoggerFactory;    

public static final ILogger LOG = LoggerFactory.create(LoggedExperiment.class);
```

Was wondering whether anyone would be able to point me in the right direction?

Have a great day.

M

Comment: Which LoggerFactory are you referring to? What's the full package name?

Comment: Hi Kiltos Kyriacou. Thank you for this. Will edit the question to add :).

Comment: *"javautils-lib-3.0.jar"*? `utils.log.*`? This doesn't look like a common library so, we don't know what that code does.

Comment: At a guess, `LoggerFactory.getLogger()` returns a singleton, creating it if necessary, and `LoggerFactory.create()` is used internally to do the creation, and should not be used by applications so as not to bypass the singleton code, but surely this package, whatever it is, has Javadoc? I would chuck it out and use `java.util.logging`.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Javadoc. Looks like this might be a custom logging framework I am working with here. Thank you all for looking into it though. Really appreciate it and sorry for the confusion. Z

Comment: If there is no Javadoc you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Yeah I know. Came with some code that was passed to us from a project which was maintained somewhere else in the past.

Comment: If you are using a modern, fully featured IDE, you should be able to step into it and view the decompiled class method bodies and find out what they do.